# Stoke's Theorem on cylinder-plane intersection.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

I was trying the solve the following exercise from Apostol Vol 2: Using Stokes theorem, proof that $\int_{C} (y-z)dx +(z-x)dy+(x-y)dz = 2 {\pi}a(a+b)$, where $C$ is the intersection of the cylinder $x^{2}+y^{2}=a^{2}$ and the plane $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{z}{b}=1$, $0<a<b$. First I computed curl$(F)=(-2,-2,-2)$, then I got $S$ to be the elliptical region bounded by $C$, i.e. the region inside $\frac{{(z-b)}^{2}} {b^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{a^2}=1$ on the $yz$ plane. Then I computed the unitary normal vector to $S$, $n=\frac{\frac{1}{a}i+\frac{1}{b}k}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}}}=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}i+\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}k$, and got curl$(F) \cdot n=\frac{-2(a+b)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$.

Stoke's theorem states that $\int_{C}F\cdot d\alpha=\iint_S curl(F) \cdot dS$, so in this case that would be $\int_{C}F\cdot d\alpha= \frac{-2(a+b)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \iint_S dS$. The double integral in the latter formula is the area of the ellipse, $\pi ab$. The answer would be $\frac{-2ab\pi(a+b)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$, which does not resembles at all to the answer I should be getting.

I already got the right answer by taking the parametrization of the surface $(rcos(\theta), rsin(\theta),b-\frac{brcos(\theta)}{a})$, with $0\le \theta \le 2\pi$ and $0\le r \le a$ but I'm still wondering what went wrong with the steps AND reasoning I showed previously. I know that the same question was already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594000/to-evaluate-a-line-integral-along-the-curve-of-intersection-of-the-cylinder-x2) but the answers don't mention anything like this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe one mistake you are making is your calculation for the area of the ellipse as $\pi ab$. The ellipse does not lie simply in the $(y,z)$ plane. If it did, the normal vector would be purely along $i$ after all.

Comment: Aside from getting the area of the ellipse wrong, per the preceding comment, the sign difference between your answer and the correct one suggests that you’re using the wrong normal.

Comment: For the normal, I know I should use the other one, the thing that was bothering me the most was the number that I got, thanks! If I wanted to calculate the area of that ellipse, what should I do? Or is it just not worth it (given that I already got the right thing with other method) Thanks again!