# Equivalence of two vector fields

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

Let $V$ be a convex region in $\mathbb R^3$ whose boundary is a closed surface $S$ and let $\vec n $ be the unit outer normal to $S$. Let $F$ and $G$ be two continuously differentiable vector fields such that $\mathop{\rm curl}  F=\mathop{\rm curl}  G; \mathop{\rm div} F=\mathop{\rm div}G$ everywhere in $V$ and $G\cdot\vec n = F\cdot\vec n$ every where on $S$. Then is it true that $F=G$ everywhere in $V$?

I tried as follows: Let $H=F-G$ , then $\mathop{\rm curl} H=O$, so there is a scalar field $f$ such that $H=\nabla f$, and also $\mathop{\rm div}  H=0$, so there is a vector field $L$ such that $H=\mathop{\rm curl} L$ but then I am stuck; please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The result follows from Green's first identity
  $$ \int_V d^3 r (\phi \nabla^2 \psi+ \vec{\nabla}\psi \cdot \vec{\nabla} \phi) =
  \oint_S d^2 r\,\phi (\vec{\nabla} \psi) \cdot \vec{n}.$$
  (this is the divergence theorem $\int_V d^3 \nabla \cdot \vec{A} = \oint_S d^2 r \vec{A}\cdot \vec{n}$ applied to $\vec{A} =\phi \vec{\nabla} \psi $)
- In order to apply it to your case, observe that because the fields $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{G}$ are rotation free, you can find a scalar field $\phi$ such that $\vec{F}- \vec{G} =\vec{\nabla} \phi$. Then set $\psi=\phi$ in Green's first identity.

> The following statements hold:
>
> (a) $\vec{\nabla} \phi = \vec{F} -\vec{G}$ by definition.
>
> (b) $\nabla^2 \phi =0$ as $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{G}$ are divergence free.
>
> (c) $(\vec{\nabla} \phi) \cdot \vec{n} =0$ on the surface $S$ (as $\vec F\cdot \vec{n} =0$ and $\vec G\cdot \vec{n} =0$).

- Thus, we have that  $$ \int_V d^3 r (\phi\underbrace{ \nabla^2 \phi}_{=0}+ \vec{\nabla}\phi \cdot \vec{\nabla} \phi) =
  \oint_S d^2 r\,\phi \underbrace{(\vec{\nabla} \phi) \cdot \vec{n}}_{=0}.$$
  Thus Green's first identity implies
  $$ 0=  \int_V d^3 r \,\vec{\nabla}\phi \cdot \vec{\nabla} \phi= \int_V d^3 r\, |\vec{\nabla} \phi|^2 = \int_V d^3 r\,| \vec{F} -\vec{G}|^2$$
  from which we conclude that $\vec{F} =\vec{G}$ on $V$.

Comment: That $\iiint_V ||F-G||^2 dxdydz=0$ was already clear to me from your previous work . My query is how does that imply $||F-G||=0$ ?

Comment: If you integrate a positive function, and the result is 0 what you can conclude about the integrand?

Comment: yes yes , I know that in real analysis ; so it also holds for several variables ? Ok . And could you please take a look at this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1593812/c-be-curve-of-intersection-of-hemisphere-x2y2z2-2ax-and-cylinder-x2y now ? Thanks